# Issue uploading an image file

Tags: php, file-upload

I am having troubles getting a query which includes an img file to upload to my database. The error I am receiving currently is:

> **Notice**:  Use of undefined constant UploadFile - assumed
>   'UploadFile'

Which is this line of code:

`return UploadFile;`

I don't get what I am doing wrong. This error is right before the query, so it is stopping it from executing.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Form

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="projectForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Project Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="input block" name="p_name">
    <label>Project Img</label>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" class="file-input block">
    <button id="submit">Submit Project</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
$('#projectForm').validate({
    ignore: [],
    rules: {
        p_name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        }
    },
    messages: {
        p_name: {
            required: "Please enter the project name",
            minlength: "The project name is too short"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form, e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(form);
        category = $(this).data('category');

        console.log(category);


        $.ajax({
            url: '/php/projectSend.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            success: function (data) {
                /*if (data == null) {
                    alert("Unable to sned project!");
                    alert(data);
                } else {
                    var displayProjects = JSON.parse(data);
                        console.log(this.html);
                });*/
                alert("Sent");

            },
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + " | " + errorThrown);
                alert('There are currently no project images for this selection');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

PHP

```
$p_name = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['p_name'], ENT_QUOTES));

// If you make a file function, you can change where things are saved
// You can also change the destination (for portability)
    function UploadFile($fileArray, $destinationFolder = '../project_images/') {
        //$p_img = $fileArray['file'];

        $fileUploadData = $fileArray['file'];
        var_dump($fileUploadData);
        $filename       =   $fileUploadData['name'];
        $tmp_name       =   $fileUploadData['tmp_name'];
        $filesize       =   $fileUploadData['size'];
        $file_error     =   $fileUploadData['error'];
        //$file           =   $fileArray['file'];

        /*
        $filename       =   $fileArray[$fileNameVar];
        $tmp_name       =   $fileArray[$fileTmpNameVar];
        $filesize       =   $fileArray[$fileSizeVar];
        $file_error     =   $fileArray[$fileErrorVar];
        $file           =   $fileArray[$p_img];
*/
        var_dump($filename);
        // Save all the default data.
        // Success and error should be set by default to fail
        $return['error']        =   true;
        $return['success']      =   false;
        $return['file']['dest'] =   $destinationFolder.$filename;
        $return['file']['size'] =   $filesize;

        if($file_error == 0)
            $return['error']    =   false;
        // directory creation function so no manual
        if(!is_dir($destinationFolder))
            mkdir($destinationFolder,0755,true);
        // If filename is not empty, return success or fail of upload
        if (!empty($filename))
            $return['success']  = (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $destinationFolder.$filename));

        return $return;
    }
    if (UploadFile  == true) {
        return UploadFile;
    } else {
        var_dump("UploadFile Failed");
    }

try {
    $con = getConfig('pdo');
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// save-to-database function
    function SaveToDb($con,$filename = false) {
        // Return fail immediately if the connection is false or image is invalid
        if(empty($filename) || !$con)
            return false;
        $project_sql = "
            INSERT INTO quotes
            (p_name, p_img, date_added)
            VALUES(?, ?, NOW())
        ";
        if ($project_stmt = $con->prepare($project_sql)) {
            $project_stmt->execute(array($p_name, $p_img));
            return true;
            $proj_succ = "Success";
            echo json_encode($proj_succ);
        }
        return false;
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    file_put_contents('error_log_new', "\n[{$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}]" . "Error adding attachment: \n" . print_r($e, 1), FILE_APPEND);
}

    if(isset($_POST['create'])) {
        // Try uploading
        $upload =   UploadFile($_FILES);
        // If upload fails
        if(!$upload['success']) {
            echo '<h3>Sorry, an error occurred</h3>';
        }
        else {

            // save it
            $saveToDb   =   SaveToDb($con,$upload['file']['dest']);
            // Get the profile from image name
            $profPic    =   ($saveToDb)? getPhoto($con,$upload['file']['dest']) : false;   
        }
    }
```

Comment: `UploadFile` is a function not a constant. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte When I remove that small section of code, it still doesn't send to the db.

Comment: I don't even know if my img file is getting to my php file. I try var dumping the $filename variable, but I never get anything.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the following code as it is incorrect and doing nothing. `UploadFile` is a function and therefore needs parameters passing to it, which you aren't doing here:

```
if (UploadFile  == true) {
    return UploadFile;
} else {
    var_dump("UploadFile Failed");
}
```

You are accessing the `UploadFile()` function further down, but only if there is an input present called "create", which it doesn't look like there is in your HTML.

So, change the line:

```
if(isset($_POST['create'])) {
```

to:

```
if(isset($_POST['p_name']) && isset($_FILES)) {
```

This will ensure the name is present and a file has been uploaded. Alternatively add an input called "create" in the HTML if there's some reason you need that line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="create" value="true">
```